# can we Extend application and uiapplication on same project?

Tags: blackberry

plz tell me can we extend Uiapplication and application class in blackberry.?
if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just have separate classes extending them. It's your

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

method that is going to determine behavior: you would look at the argument coming in and decide whether to launch the UiApplication or Application.

Create a second project in the workspace, and in properties set it up as an "alternate entry point for " and then you can specify the arguments given to main.

Generally you'd make the 'base' project start the Application (a service I'm assuming - e.g. automatic startup, system module) and then you'd set the alternate entry point to pass "GUI" or some other token to main, and you'd create your UiApplication instance instead.